# What's that sound? Is it my childhood?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, video-games

> Even your mother may have heard of me, I'm as iconic as who I represent.
> Ecstacy will fill your body with glee, as you start and when my sounds I present.
>
> Except those who never knew the joy, of jumping through clouds or exploring underground.
> Celebrated by most fanboys, they may even cry and cheer when they hear my sound.
>
> Especially when you show them my original form,
> Great waves of nerds and fans alike may arise and storm.

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you the

> Mario theme song?

Even your mother may have heard of me, I'm as iconic as who I represent.

> It's an iconic theme song, and so is Mario.

Ecstasy will fill your body with glee, as you start and when my sounds I present.

> The sounds make you happy because they're the soundtrack of my childhood too.

Except those who never knew the joy, of jumping through clouds or exploring underground.

> Part of the Mario games, you wouldn't know the theme song if you didn't play.

Celebrated by most fanboys, they may even cry and cheer when they hear my sound.

> Same as above, I had friends who learned this on the piano (and yes, so did I, at one point ;P).

Especially when you show them my original form,

> Especially the original Mario theme song with all of its metallic sounding glory.

Great waves of nerds and fans alike may arise and storm.

> Everybody knows the theme song!

The secret hint is

> The acrostic, EEE CEG, the opening 6 notes to the theme song.

And yes, that is indeed the sound of my childhood!! :D

Comment: Wow, this was much faster than I thought it would be. There's a hidden clue, can you find it?

Comment: When you mentioned acrostic in one of your comments, I looked and I had a minor freakout

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> One of the mario games, assumedly one of the older versions?

Even your mother may have heard of me, I'm as iconic as who I represent.

> Everyone's heard of mario

Ecstacy will fill your body with glee, as you start and when my sounds I present.

> If it's mariokart, the 3-2-1-GO! The retro music in other mario games is iconic too, especially when you get coins.

Except those who never knew the joy, of jumping through clouds or exploring underground.

> There are cloud and underground levels

Celebrated by most fanboys, they may even cry and cheer when they hear my sound.

> Everyone loves mario, and it's quite competitive

Especially when you show them my original form,

> the '64 version

Great waves of nerds and fans alike may arise and storm.

> is hella popular

Comment: No, but you're on the right track. You are right that it has to do with rot13(Znevb), but it's more specific than that.

Comment: More specific as in it's one of the games in the franchise? 'Cause I'm one of those poor saps who's never experienced the clouds or the tunnels :')

Comment: Even more specific than one of the games, I'm afraid. I usually have acrostics in my riddles, is there one in this one too?

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> A level up in Mario/course complete.

Even your mother may have heard of me, I'm as iconic as who I represent.

> It was founded in 1983 and the level ups have been there since then.

Ecstacy will fill your body with glee, as you start and when my sounds I present.

> Extra life!

Except those who never knew the joy, of jumping through clouds or exploring underground.

> The sewer levels, and the cloud world.

Celebrated by most fanboys, they may even cry and cheer when they hear my sound.

> They have The national Mario day.

Especially when you show them my original form,
Great waves of nerds and fans alike may arise and storm.

> Nothing beats the classics

Comment: The answer is more specific than this, though you are on the right track.

Comment: Is this any different @Joe-You-Know?

Comment: Much more specific! But not quite the answer I'm looking for. Sounds are important!